# How to give url from links inside WebView when user click it

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have a WebView. It contains page, filtered by Jsoup.

```
    WebView cntContent;
    WebView cntComments;
    WebSettings webSettingsContent;
    WebSettings webSettingsComments;

        cntContent = findViewById(R.id.cntContent);
        cntComments = findViewById(R.id.cntComments);
        webSettingsContent = cntContent.getSettings();
        webSettingsComments = cntComments.getSettings();
        webSettingsContent.setDefaultFontSize(16);
        webSettingsComments.setDefaultFontSize(16);

        cntContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        cntComments.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webSettingsContent.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettingsComments.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        cntContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentUrl, contentFinal, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        cntComments.loadDataWithBaseURL(contentUrl, commentsFinal, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        cntContent.setClickable(true);
```

Page contains links. **How can I give url of link when user click it and put url to String?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is supply the WebView with your own WebViewClient.
Subclass the WebViewClient and use the WebView method setWebViewClient to set it.
Then in the WebViewClient override the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method and do whatever you like with the link.

```
WebView wv = new WebView();
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                return false;
            }
        });
```